# Referncing XML in jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, xml, google-app-engine

I've got to parse an XML document for AJAX dynamic population.  I'm getting this error, however.

```
(document).ready(function(){var departure=$('#departure'); arrival=$('#arrival');
$.ajax({type:"GET", url:"cities.xml", dataType:"xml", success: function(xml)


INFO     2013-02-22 18:16:06,951 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /cities.xml HTTP/1.1" 40
```

I've got my **cities.xml** file in the same directory as the template that loads it.

```
/templates/template_with_jquery
/templates/cities.xml
```

Does anyone know why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Is cities.xml available at /cities.xml when opening in your browser? What python framework are you running?

Comment: I'm running this on a local google app engine development server for an app I'm developing.

Comment: Is cities.xml supposed to be a template or a static file? What does your handlers look like? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Required_Elements

Comment: - url: /updates
  static_files: /templates/cities.xml
  upload: /templates/cities.xml

Comment: resulted in:  ERROR    2013-02-22 21:20:43,180 dev_appserver.py:2048] Error encountered reading file "/templates/cities.xml":
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/templates/cities.xml'

Answer (score 1):

local urls are relative to the top level, not from whatever level the js file is at. Looks like you're getting a 404 because there is no such file as `<yoursite>/cities.xml`.

change your url to "`/templates/cities.xml`" and you should be fine.

Comment: INFO     2013-02-22 18:40:48,986 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET    /templates/cities.xml HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: are you *sure* that the FULL PATH to cities.xml is <yoursite>/templates/cities.xml? A 404 means that file isn't there, which means your url is wrong.

Comment: the FULL path is /home/me/google_projects/app_name/templates/cities.xml; which I also tried.

Comment: INFO     2013-02-22 18:56:00,089 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET   /maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: tell me about your project structure. And I didn't mean full path on your computer, I meant full path relative to the top level of your site, sorry. Your urls are not in sync with your file structure.

Comment: That's ok, I'm pretty new to this...  I've got my project structure like I always do, main.py, index.yaml, static, and templates are within app_name directory; within templates we have /template1.html,template2.html,cities.xml,another_template.html.  This is pretty much how I've always got things laid out; I've never implemented jQuery parsing XML for AJAX and dynamic content generation, however.  THIS is a first, as are these errors.

Comment: no problem-- I'm new to GAE's dev server. So do you have an app.yaml file? I'm just reading through the docs to figure out what you could be missing. Is main.py within app_name?

Comment: Yes, app_name/main.py, app.yaml, index.yaml, templates, static.  I'm doing the same.  GAE is pretty sweet, otherwise, though.  I appreciate the help, btw!

Comment: GAE doesn't require you to define every path, does it? Seems like it ought to only be paths that are not exactly as specified, but I dunno... hm. Sorry I can't be of more help, other than to define a 404 :)

Comment: No, it's not exhaustive like that.  No worries!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has probably nothing to do with jQuery or XML as your are just not receiving the expected response from your dev server.

If you go to http://[your-dev-server]/cities.xml you will get a 404 as well so let's start there.

You still haven't told us if cities.xml is a template or a static file but assuming it is a static file:

Your handler:

```
url: /updates
static_files: /templates/cities.xml 
upload: /templates/cities.xml
```

means that when you go to `http://[your-dev-server]/updates` your server will send you `/templates/cities.xml`

To get the URL you are calling: `http://[your-dev-server]/cities.xml` you will have to change to:

```
url: /cities.xml
static_files: /templates/cities.xml 
upload: /templates/cities.xml
```

You should probably also remove the initial slash depending on your file structure:

```
url: /cities.xml
static_files: templates/cities.xml 
upload: templates/cities.xml
```

If cities.xml is a static file it should not really be in the templates directory as you probably want to keep templates and static files separate. Put cities.xml somewhere in a static directory with other static files like css, js and so on:

```
url: /static/xml
static_dir: static/xml 
upload: static/xml
```

This will make `static/xml/cities.xml` avaiable at `http://[your-dev-server]/static/xml/cities.xml` but also `static/xml/countries.xml` available at `http://[your-dev-server]/static/xml/countries.xml`

If cities.xml is not a static file you will have to give us some more info.

Comment: It's a static file; I made all the recommended changes and I'm now just running a little jQuery script to just LOAD the xml raising alert confirmations or errors depending on successfulness or failure.  It's failing.  I'm referencing the file in jQuery.load() method as /static/xml/cities.xml

Comment: But does http://[your-dev-machine]/static/xml/cities.xml work if you open it directly in your browser (no jquery)? You need to add more relevant info to your question (full jquery method, app.yaml and so on) or we won't be able to help. You obviously need to change your ajax call to the new path as well: url:"/static/xml/countries.xml" if you haven't already.

Comment: I realize I should have been much more thorough, now.  Although, even whilst sharing screens with a professional friend of mine the issue was not clear with full code in view.  Your assistance is most appreciated, and I apologize for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

This was a technicality issue from the beginning to end.  I must say, I've learned a valuable lesson about the importance of yaml files in App Engine, however.  The change was as follows in the **app.yaml** file

**original:**

1)

```
url: /static/xml
static_dir: static/xml
upload: static/xml
```

2)

```
url: /static/xml
static_files: static/xml
upload: static/xml/cities.xml
```

**correct & final:**

```
url:/static/xml
static_dir: static/xml
```

The **upload** regular expression I was passing wasn't matching with anything.  Anyway, this was just one of those off by one, but seems like a hundred, errors.

Comment: It is, with the exception of **upload**.